# Scss | Sass @use and @forward issue?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

im trying to make a sass structer with sass @use and @forward i dont want to use @import but i was get an error.

-abstracts (Folder)

--- _veriables.scss

```
  $dGray: #7c7c7c;
```

--- _index.scss

```
 @forward "./veriables";
```

--- style.scss

```
@use './abstracts/' as *;

* {
  color: $dGray;
}
```

what is the mistake this is not working. why? thanks so much for help

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue it with this vscode [extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codelios.dartsass)